# Vim Configuration for expl3

Tags: highlighting, vim, expl3

I've started with programming in `expl3` and `vim` doesn't realise that underscores are now part of LaTeX identifiers.

I'd be much obliged if somebody could explain how to best configure `vim` so it has the "usual" word boundaries, including underscores, and also does syntax highlighting of words properly.

I know it should be possible to find this information in the `vim` documentation, but I prefer a quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: Very interesting question! `:)` It would be nice to have a LaTeX3 capable editor.

Comment: Future comment: worth noting that [the vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) has support for expl3 syntax highlighting now (although with my Egyptian bracket convention it does not indent too well)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Quick and dirty solution

```
:syn match texStatement "\\[a-zA-Z_:]\+"
```

or add `@`

```
:syn match texStatement "\\[a-zA-Z_:@]\+"
```

It isn't enough, but looks much better.

### But better

Modify `$VIM/syntax/tex.vim`, search `b:tex_stylish`, and modify all expressions about it.

Comment: Fantastic answer! `:)`

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Well, the location of `tex.vim` is quite different between various platforms. e.g. `~/.vim/vimfiles/syntax`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen `:help vimfiles`

Comment: @LeoLiu Thanks. I've just started reinstalling `vim`. Looks promising already. I'm now in the process of changing the LaTeX keywords.

Comment: @LeoLiu Finally managed to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is great! As the syntax lighting files can be updated when vim is updated I've put this in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`.